# python random number generator function

Tags: python

I have a function that generates a random integer and appends in list till the number is generated again and if it matches with the number in the list than the list is returned.

```
from random import randint
def randomizerfinder(length):
    mylist = []
    is_done = False
    while (is_done == False):
        r = randint(1,length)
        is_found = False
        for n in mylist:
            if (n==r):
                is_found = True
                break
        if (is_found == False):
            mylist.append(r)
        if (len(mylist) == length):
            is_done=True
    return mylist

x=randomizerfinder(10)
print (x)
```

I am a beginner in python. Kindly suggest how I can write it precisely in lesser lines of code

Comment: You should use the keyword `in` for the checks

Comment: I assume your indentation is off, the return shouldn't be inside the while loop?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to another community, Code Golf.

Comment: Please post your question on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should use the keyword `in` to decrease the `if` and evaluations you are making:

```
from random import randint
def randomizerfinder(length):
    mylist = []
    r = randint(1,length)
    while (r not in mylist) and (length > len(mylist)):
      mylist.append(r)
      r = randint(1,length)
    return mylist
x=randomizerfinder(10)
print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 5, 8, 4, 10, 7]
```